# UITextField to sms recipents

Tags: objective-c, ios, sms, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that the user will enter a cell phone number.The user touches a IBAction button and it is passed to the MFMessageComposeViewController sms recipients.it seems that the recipients will not alow a NSString to be used.Passing a NSString to the body works but not the recipients.

```
-(IBAction)buttonSMS: (id)sender
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    picker.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"15557774444", nil];
    picker.body = textField.text;
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

}
```

this is what i tried

```
picker.recipients = telField.text;
```

in place of

```
picker.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"15557774444", nil];
```

Can some one point me in the rite direction with some sample code.....please and thankyou

Expert in all things html,javascript and css but newbee in objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `recipients` property is of type `NSArray *`. A string is not. You must wrap the string in an array, like so: `[NSArray arrayWithObject:telField.text]`.